# Shortcut for open a recently closed file/Tab in MyEclipse Editor

Tags: tabs, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcut, myeclipse

I know i can do it by ***Alt+f then 1 or 2 or 3***. Is there a way give new shortcut in MyEclipse. I unable to find & set it under **Windows > Preferences > General > Keys**.

For Example: I have opened a file called *Task.java* in MyEclipse. I closed it accidentally. Now i want to open it again without navigating through *Package Explorer*.

I want Something similar,

> Ctrl + Shift+ T

to open recently closed Tab in the Firefox & Google Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to view all the shortcut keys , Press the **same** once again to open the Keys Binding dialog.

Type the text in the filter text box *for eg. activate* , you will get Activate Editor in the search result list with default key of <kbd>F11</kbd>.

Double click it and choose your favorite key you want in the Bindings say <kbd>F9</kbd>. Click Apply to Change it. Click OK.

**Illustration**

[image]